# i18n detectBrowserLanguage is not working

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I have an issue with detectBrowserLanguage from i18n, when using it as a module in Nuxt. Even though my browser is set to English, I still see the website in Spanish, and I'm not sure how to make it work.

**nuxt.config**

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "@nuxtjs/i18n"],
  i18n: {
    vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts",
  },
```

**i18n.config**

```
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
  locale: "es",
  fallbackLocale: "es",
  legacy: false,
  detectBrowserLanguage: {
    useCookie: true,
    cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
    alwaysRedirect: true,
    onlyOnRoot: true,
  },
  fallbackWarn: false,
  missingWarn: false,
  warnHtmlMessage: false,
  messages: {
    es: { //msgs }, en: {//msgs}
```

Besides, I have a component for manually and preferably changing the language. I made changes to it according to those configuration settings from detectBrowserLanguage.

```
<script>
import SDropdown from "~/Components/utils/SDropdown.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentLanguage: this.$i18n.locale,
      detectedLanguage: this.$i18n.locale,
      supportedLanguagesFlagIcons: {
        es: "/assets/icons/ES.svg",
        en: "/assets/icons/en.svg",
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    SDropdown,
  },
  methods: {
    setLanguage(languageCode) {
      this.$i18n.locale = languageCode;
      this.currentLanguage = languageCode;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.detectedLanguage = this.$i18n.locale;
    this.currentLanguage = this.$i18n.locale;
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <SDropdown align="right" width="48">
    <template #trigger>
      <button
        class="inline-flex text-sm border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition"
      ></button>

      <span class="inline-flex rounded-md">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="inline-flex items-center text-xl no-underline py-2 px-4 navLink leading-4 transition capitalize"
        >
          <img
            class="w-10"
            :src="supportedLanguagesFlagIcons[currentLanguage]"
            :alt="$t(currentLanguage)"
          />
          <svg
            class="ml-2 -mr-0.5 h-4 w-4"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
          >
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </span>
    </template>
    <template #content>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="block px-3 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 no-underline navLink"
        @click.prevent="setLanguage('es')"
      >
        <img
          class="w-8 inline-block mr-2"
          :src="supportedLanguagesFlagIcons.es"
        />
        Español
      </a>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="block px-3 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 no-underline navLink"
        @click.prevent="setLanguage('en')"
      >
        <img
          class="w-8 inline-block mr-2"
          :src="supportedLanguagesFlagIcons.en"
        />
        English
      </a>
    </template>
  </SDropdown>
</template>
```

I only hope to solve this error and be able to have the page in English already in this case, since my search bar is in English... otherwise, it should appear in Spanish.

Furthermore, in the console, I executed the command: navigator.languages, and I obtained the following response:

navigator.languages
['en']0: "en"length: 1

Comment: I've managed to have the page detect the browser's language, but when moving to another route, the language switches to Spanish. The search engine remains in English. Interestingly, upon returning to the index, the page is back in English.

`` `nuxt.config.ts
i18n: {
  locales: ["en", "es"],
  defaultLocale: "es",
  detectBrowserLanguage: {
    useCookie: false,
    cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
    alwaysRedirect: true,
    redirectOn: "root",
  },
  vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts",
},
`` `

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/basic-usage) not all the settings go under `i18n.config`.

This should work for you:

- nuxt.config.ts

```js
i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'es',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
        useCookie: true,
        cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
        alwaysRedirect: true,
        onlyOnRoot: true,
    },
    vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts",
    // ...
}
```

- i18n.config.ts

```js
export default defineI18nConfig(() => {
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'es',
    messages: {
        es: { //msgs },
        en: {//msgs}
    // ...
})
```

Comment: Yes, I've set it up that way now, but it still doesn't work. It displays the index in English, but when I navigate to another route, it switches back to Spanish. And after trying again, it wasn't even doing that anymore. I don't understand why it's causing so much difficulty.

Comment: I've managed to have the page detect the browser's language, but when moving to another route, the language switches to Spanish. The search engine remains in English. Interestingly, upon returning to the index, the page is back in English.

`` `nuxt.config.ts
i18n: {
  locales: ["en", "es"],
  defaultLocale: "es",
  detectBrowserLanguage: {
    useCookie: false,
    cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
    alwaysRedirect: true,
    redirectOn: "root",
  },
  vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts",
},
`` `

Answer (score 0):

just remove this

`locale: "es",`

from

```
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
//  locale: "es",
```